# the last modified value of the list is not getting save in shared Preferences on one click of save button but gets saved after twice clicking save btn

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

i'm trying to display azan names with their timings on a recyclerview in android studio java, when user opens the app, the default code done by adding library displays the timings and infront of the azan names and timings, there's a edit icon to edit the timings of azan , at first the timings of azan will be non-editable and on click of edit Icon user will be able to edit them. the flag status turns true if the data is modified and and the modified data must be saved to sharedPreferences. when user opens the app , in the onCreateView the controller must check whether the data is modified or not, ,if not it should call the defaultAzantiming() method otherwise load the data from sharedPreferences. it is doing as per requirements except the last value of list which is modified doesn't gets saved in shared Preferences at one time click on save btn but if i click two times on save btn, it saves the modified value in shahred Preferencnes. I'm not being able to identify the issue.

Here's my code:

Adapter.java:

```
public class AzanAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AzanAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private List<AzanTiming> azanTimings;
    private Context context;
    private SaveListener saveListener;
    public boolean isAnyItemInEditMode = false;

    public AzanAdapter(Context context, List<AzanTiming> azanTimings) {
        this.context = context;
        this.azanTimings = azanTimings;
    }
    public void setSaveListener(SaveListener listener) {
        saveListener = listener;
    }

    public interface SaveListener {
        void onSaveClicked();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_azan_timing, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AzanTiming azanTiming = azanTimings.get(position);
//        Log.d("AzanTiming", "onBindViewHolder: " + azanTiming.getName() + " - Edited: " + azanTiming.isEditable());
        holder.nameTextView.setText(azanTiming.getName());
        holder.timeTextView.setText(azanTiming.getTime());

        if (azanTiming.isEditable()) {
            holder.timeTextView.setEnabled(true);
            holder.timeTextView.requestFocus(); // Focus on EditText
        } else {
            holder.timeTextView.setEnabled(false);
            holder.timeTextView.clearFocus(); // Clear focus
        }

        holder.editIcon.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Clear the focus from other items
            for (AzanTiming timing : azanTimings) {
                timing.setEditable(false);
            }
            azanTiming.setEditable(true);
            isAnyItemInEditMode = true; // Set the flag to true
            holder.timeTextView.requestFocus();
            // holder.timeTextView.clearFocus(); <-- Remove this line
            // Notify the fragment to update the visibility of the "Save" button
            if (saveListener != null) {
                saveListener.onSaveClicked();
            }
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        });



        holder.timeTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                String editedTime = holder.timeTextView.getText().toString();
                if (!editedTime.equals(azanTiming.getOriginalTime())) {
                    azanTiming.setTime(editedTime);
                    azanTiming.setEditable(true); // Data is modified, set isEdited to true
                } else {
                    azanTiming.setEditable(false); // Data is unchanged, set isEdited to false
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return azanTimings.size();
    }

    public boolean isAnyItemInEditMode() {
//        Toast.makeText(context, "adapterSaveMethood "+isAnyItemInEditMode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return isAnyItemInEditMode;
    }

    void saveTimingsToSharedPreferences(List<AzanTiming> updatedTimings) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(updatedTimings); // Serialize the updated timings
        Log.d("json","json: "+json);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("azanTimings", json);
        editor.putBoolean("isAnyItemInEditMode", isAnyItemInEditMode); // Save the edit mode flag
        editor.apply();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Azan timing data saved to SharedPreferences", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    public void updateAndSaveTimings(List<AzanTiming> updatedTimings) {
        azanTimings = updatedTimings;
        isAnyItemInEditMode = false; // Reset the flag when the timings are saved
        notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify the RecyclerView of the data change
    }



    public List<AzanTiming> getAzanTimings() {
        return azanTimings;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView nameTextView;
        TextView timeTextView;
        ImageView editIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameAzan);
            timeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeAzan);
            editIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editAzanTimingIcon);
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment.java:

```
package com.example.qibladirectionandtasbeeh;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.batoulapps.adhan.CalculationMethod;
import com.batoulapps.adhan.CalculationParameters;
import com.batoulapps.adhan.Coordinates;
import com.batoulapps.adhan.Madhab;
import com.batoulapps.adhan.PrayerTimes;
import com.batoulapps.adhan.data.DateComponents;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class azan extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView azanRecyclerView;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    AzanAdapter adapter;

    private ImageView notificationIcon;
    ImageView editIcon;
    private TextView azanTimingtxt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_azan, container, false);

        azanRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.azanRecyclerView);
        azanRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        editIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.editAzanTimingIcon);

        List<AzanTiming> azanTimings = getAzanTimings();
        adapter = new AzanAdapter(getContext(), azanTimings);

        azanRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Button saveBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        // Set the initial visibility of the "Save" button
        saveBtn.setVisibility(adapter.isAnyItemInEditMode() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        // Update the visibility of the "Save" button when the edit icon is clicked
        adapter.setSaveListener(new AzanAdapter.SaveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSaveClicked() {
                saveBtn.setVisibility(adapter.isAnyItemInEditMode() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> saveUpdatedTimings());
        return view;
    }

    private List<AzanTiming> calculateDefaultAzanTimings() {
        List<AzanTiming> defaultAzanTimings = loadTimingsFromSharedPreferences();

        // If no timings found in SharedPreferences, use the initial calculation method
        if (defaultAzanTimings.isEmpty()) {
            Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(32.4945, 74.5229);

            CalculationParameters params = CalculationMethod.KARACHI.getParameters();
            params.madhab = Madhab.HANAFI;
            params.adjustments.fajr = 2;

            PrayerTimes prayerTimes = new PrayerTimes(coordinates, DateComponents.from(new Date()), params);

            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());

            defaultAzanTimings.add(new AzanTiming("Fajr", timeFormat.format(prayerTimes.fajr)));
            defaultAzanTimings.add(new AzanTiming("Sunrise", timeFormat.format(prayerTimes.sunrise)));
            defaultAzanTimings.add(new AzanTiming("Dhuhr", timeFormat.format(prayerTimes.dhuhr)));
            defaultAzanTimings.add(new AzanTiming("Asr", timeFormat.format(prayerTimes.asr)));
            defaultAzanTimings.add(new AzanTiming("Maghrib", timeFormat.format(prayerTimes.maghrib)));
            defaultAzanTimings.add(new AzanTiming("Isha", timeFormat.format(prayerTimes.isha)));

            // Save the initial timings to SharedPreferences
            adapter.saveTimingsToSharedPreferences(defaultAzanTimings);

            // Mark all timings as not edited
            for (AzanTiming timing : defaultAzanTimings) {
                timing.setEditable(false);
            }
        }

        return defaultAzanTimings;
    }


    private List<AzanTiming> loadTimingsFromSharedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("azanTimings", "");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<AzanTiming>>() {}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }

    private void saveUpdatedTimings() {
        List<AzanTiming> updatedTimings = adapter.getAzanTimings(); // Get the updated timings from the adapter
        adapter.saveTimingsToSharedPreferences(updatedTimings); // Save the updated timings to SharedPreferences
        adapter.updateAndSaveTimings(updatedTimings); // Update the timings and refresh the RecyclerView

        Log.d("updated list","UpdatedList: "+updatedTimings);
//        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "updated list: "+updatedTimings, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Notify the user about successful saving
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Timings saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    private List<AzanTiming> getAzanTimings() {
        List<AzanTiming> azanTimings = loadTimingsFromSharedPreferences();

        if (azanTimings.isEmpty()) {
            azanTimings = calculateDefaultAzanTimings();
        }

        return azanTimings;
    }


}
```